# Git Server setup in local server

Tags: git

For the installation of the git server and git client in the local machine in the same network isn't working, can you get me the steps and commands for using for the setup of the git in a local machine in Ubuntu 16.04 .

Comment: What do you mean by "git server" and "git client" and "isn't working"? And what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: You don't need a "git server" at all. `git` is a *distributed* version control system. It works *locally* on *local* repositories and pushes changes to *remote* repositories. Which can easily be other local folders or network shares

Comment: @Jijo Your question doesn't make much sense. Did you think you need a "server" to work locally? Or are you asking how to set up a git daemon in your LAN so many developers can work with the same remote repository? You don't need a "server" to work on a local repo. You can start a daemon with `git daemon`

Comment: yes i want to setup in local ,which in my LAN so many developers can work with the same remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Gitolite`

Read here on how to do it:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html

#### `Gitolite`

> Gitolite allows you to setup git hosting on a central server, with fine-grained access control and many more powerful features.

#### Installing for source

```
su - <your user>
mkdir -p ~/bin

# grab the source
git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

# build and install from source
# !!! Important Make sure `~/bin` is in `$PATH`. 
gitolite/install -ln ~/bin          
gitolite setup -pk yourname.pub
```

#### Using apt

```
# install form binary
sudo apt install gitolite
```

Comment: Or simply run `git daemon`.

Comment: Hmm, hmm… advising a novice who cannot install git to install and configure gitolite… isn't it too much?

Comment: Agree, but others who will see this post, later on, can learn from it as well and I gave a very detailed script so he simply needs to copy and paste. didn't give a general solution but a very detailed one.